# Java-Netbeans: ¿Como imprimir un método que se encuentra dentro de una clase heredada, si en la misma clase hay un método abstracto?

Tags: java, netbeans, herencia, clase-abstracta

*Necesito calcular el Aporte del EmpleadoOficina y Clasificar al EmpleadoVendedor mediante metodos.

Quisiera saber como puedo hacer para imprimir los metodos Aporte() y Clasif() que ya están creados y se encuentran en las clases heredadas ya que también en ellas está un método abstracto que es el Salario()*

**Esta es la clase Empresa en donde calculo los Ingresos Totales de los empleados**

```
public class Empresa {
        private Empleado empleados[];

    public Empresa(Empleado[] empleados) {
        this.empleados = empleados;
    }

    public Empleado[] getEmpleados() {
        return empleados;
    }

    public void setEmpleados(Empleado[] empleados) {
        this.empleados = empleados;
    }

   public double IngresosTotales(){
   double ingreso = 0;
       for (int i = 0; i < empleados.length; i++) {
           ingreso += empleados[i].Salario();
       }

   return ingreso;
   }



}
```

**Esta es la clase Empleado**

```
public abstract class Empleado {
    protected String nombre,sexo,cedula;
    protected int edad;
    protected double ventasRealizadas;

    public Empleado(String nombre, String sexo, String cedula, int edad, double ventasRealizadas) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.sexo = sexo;
        this.cedula = cedula;
        this.edad = edad;
        this.ventasRealizadas = ventasRealizadas;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getSexo() {
        return sexo;
    }

    public void setSexo(String sexo) {
        this.sexo = sexo;
    }

    public String getCedula() {
        return cedula;
    }

    public void setCedula(String cedula) {
        this.cedula = cedula;
    }

    public int getEdad() {
        return edad;
    }

    public void setEdad(int edad) {
        this.edad = edad;
    }

    public double getVentasRealizadas() {
        return ventasRealizadas;
    }

    public void setVentasRealizadas(double ventasRealizadas) {
        this.ventasRealizadas = ventasRealizadas;
    }



    public abstract double Salario();

}
```

**Esta es la clase EmpleadoOficina que hereda de Empleado**

```
public class EmpleadoOficina extends Empleado{
    private final double Salario = 376.00;

    public EmpleadoOficina(String nombre, String sexo, String cedula, int edad, double ventasRealizadas) {
        super(nombre, sexo, cedula, edad, ventasRealizadas);
    }  



    @Override
   public double Salario(){
   double salario = 0;
   salario = Salario + (ventasRealizadas*0.1);

   return salario;
    }



    public double Aporte(){

        if (Salario>550) {

        return Salario*0.949;
        } else {

            return 0;
        }


    }


}
```

**Esta es la clase EmpleadoVendedor que hereda de Empleado**

```
public class EmpleadoVendedor extends Empleado{

    public EmpleadoVendedor(String nombre, String sexo, String cedula, int edad, int ventasRealizadas) {
        super(nombre, sexo, cedula, edad, ventasRealizadas);
    }


@Override
   public double Salario(){
   double salario = 0;
   salario = ventasRealizadas*0.15;

   return salario;

    }

  public String Clasif(){

      if (Salario()> 1000 ) {
          return "lider";
      } else if(Salario()>500){
          return "rentables";
      } else if(Salario()<=500){
        return "buenos";
      } else if (Salario()<376.00){return "Nada";} 


       return Clasif();

  }


}
```

**Y esta es la clase EmpresaVentas donde se encuentra el main**

```
public class EmpresaVentas {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Empleado empleado1 = new EmpleadoOficina("Juan", "Masculino", "17130067", 40, 35);
        Empleado empleado2 = new EmpleadoVendedor("Johan", "Masculino", "1716545", 20, 30);
        Empleado[] grupo1;
        grupo1 = new Empleado[2];
        grupo1[0] = empleado1;
        grupo1[1] = empleado2;


        Empresa e = new Empresa(grupo1);
        System.err.println("Los ingresos totales a pagar por la empresa a los empleados es de: " +e.IngresosTotales());




    }


}
```

Comment: Esto huele a tarea ¿ya intentaste casteando antes de invocar el método?

Comment: La verdad soy nuevo en esto y recién estoy aprendiendo,no he casteado, no se si me podrías ayudar, no es una tarea solamente quisiera saber si hay alguna manera de mostrar esos métodos @GustavoAriasMéndez

Comment: if (empleado1 instanceof EmpleadoOficina) {
  EmpleadoOficina eo = (EmpleadoOficina) empleado1;
  System.out.println(eo.Aporte());
}

Comment: Listo, aclaraste mi duda, Muchas Gracias, ya me funcionó @GustavoAriasMéndez

Comment: Que gusto, eso de poner entre parentesis la clas EmpleadoOficina para convertir (castear) el objeto empleado1 se llama casteo

Comment: Sí tienes razón le estaba investigando y es muy útil, Muchas Gracias. @GustavoAriasMéndez